# What's the correct way to define the start-screen in an angular PWA?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have my app available as a PWA. However if the user downloads it then their default screen is exactly the same as the web default screen which is the front page of the site.

However since it's now effectively 'installed' on the user's phone, I want the front page of the site to be a login screen instead and to skip the website frontpage altogether.

What is the correct way to do this? I presume I should be using logic in the app itself but is there any way to define a "startup_url" in the PWA config that defines where the app opens? I've seen a `startup_url` referred to in general PWA docs but can't find anything specific to angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **start_url**

**start_url:**
the URL that loads when a user launches the application. It can be different from the main page, for example, if you want your PWA users to go directly to login page or signup page instead of home page. For analytical purposes, start_url can be crafted to indicate that the application was launched from the outside of the browser, which can be translated to PWA. That is: **"start_url": "/?launcher=homescreen"**

You can also add a queryString parameter to track homescreen activity using your server analytics. That is: **"start_url": "/?utm_source=homescreen".**

Put this into the website.webmanifest file:

```
{
    "name": "My app",
    "short_name": "My app",
    "theme_color": "white",
    "background_color": "white",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "./",

    "start_url": "/app",

    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/assets/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/assets/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally you can instruct browsers where to find the webmanifest via a meta tag on your `index.html` page

```
<!-- index.html -->
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
```

Comment: Thanks Mehdyoo. I added in a couple of bits to clarify exactly where `start_url` lives too